# Django annotate subquery's aggregation

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation, django-annotate

So I have three models

```
class Advert(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="adverts")

class Company(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class OrderRating(BaseModel):
    reported_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='ratings')
    rating = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=2,
        decimal_places=1,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1.0), MaxValueValidator(5.0)],
        help_text='Rating from 1.0 to 5.0.'
    )
```

And I'm trying to get average of all order ratings related to the company and annotate that to the `Advert` model, when I do this:

```
 qs = Advert.objects.all().annotate(
        avg_rating=Subquery(
            OrderRating.objects.filter(
               reported_company=OuterRef('company')).aggregate(Avg("rating"))["rating__avg"]
            )
        )
```

I get back stating

```
This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.'
```

Not sure where the problem is when I am calling the `OuterRef` inside a `Subquery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my experience `Subqueries` are often a bit tricky and not well documented. And they tend to return the message you are receiving when there is some error in your code defining the Subquery (not a very helpful message indeed).

As far as I know `aggregate` does not work in `Subequeries`, you must use `annotations` instead. So this should work:

```
qs = Advert.objects.all().annotate(
        avg_rating=Subquery(
            OrderRating.objects.filter(
               reported_company=OuterRef('company')).values('reported_company').annotate(av=Avg('rating')).values('av')
            )
        )
```

Comment: this sadly always returns an empty queryset

Comment: Are you saying ```qs``` or ```avg_rating``` is empty?

Comment: Actually just got it working, thanks! The problem was very interesting, under `OrderRating` meta I also had `ordering = ['created_at']` which translated the sql query not into just `ORDER BY reported_company` but to `ORDER BY reported_company, created_at`, and this was messing up everything, removing ordering fixed and now gives the correct output.

Comment: Great you got it solved. Although...the queries in this post do not use any ```order_by```?

Comment: yea I had a default ordering in the model's meta, anyway this was the problem if you're interested to read about it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by